# Problem with Select Mysql Condition Group By Order

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

Each service has different KPIs. These KPIs are ordered with the field order in the table checklist_has_kpi.
I want a list of separate services ordered by the order assigned to the KPI.

I have this query:

```
SELECT s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen 
FROM services s, kpi k, checklist_has_kpi chk 
WHERE s.serviceid=k.serviceid AND k.kpiid=chk.kpiid AND k.inreport='yes' AND chk.checklistid=61 
GROUP BY s.serviceid ORDER BY chk.order ASC
```

But it does not produce the result that I expect and I do not understand what's wrong in the query written by me.
Give me a hand?
If something is unclear just ask!
thanks

Comment: So what result do you expect?

Comment: Do you get an error?  Are the results not sorted as you would expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Then you'll see the why other RDBMS won't allow this syntax:

- 3 un-aggregated columns in SELECT but one in GROUP BY
- ORDER BY column is not in GROUP BY/SELECT and not aggregated

If you want to GROUP BY rather then DISTINCT, then you need to GROUP BY all column in the SELECT

```
SELECT s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen 
FROM services s, kpi k, checklist_has_kpi chk 
WHERE s.serviceid=k.serviceid AND k.kpiid=chk.kpiid AND k.inreport='yes' AND chk.checklistid=61 
GROUP BY s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen
```

But then you have no `chk.order` to order by, whether using GROUP BY or DISTINCT

So what about this, ignoring duplicates completely?

```
SELECT s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen 
FROM services s, kpi k, checklist_has_kpi chk 
WHERE s.serviceid=k.serviceid AND k.kpiid=chk.kpiid AND k.inreport='yes' AND chk.checklistid=61 
ORDER BY chk.order ASC
```

Or this to ORDER BY the earliest order per 3x `services` columns

```
SELECT s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen 
FROM services s, kpi k, checklist_has_kpi chk 
WHERE s.serviceid=k.serviceid AND k.kpiid=chk.kpiid AND k.inreport='yes' AND chk.checklistid=61 
GROUP BY s.serviceid, s.servicenameit, s.servicenameen
ORDER BY MIN(chk.order)
```

Comment: I Love you! The key to the solution to the problem was the MIN! Thank you so much!